# Audit question failures

Tags: discussion, review-audits, scope, unclear

I keep "failing" audit questions where people marked the question as "Unclear what you're asking" (perhaps because they were annoyed with the question asked).

In most of these cases it's quite clear what the person was asking. What are the options here?

As my [most recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8046022), I felt it was fairly clear that they were looking for an alternate way of viewing the function definition (like just typing it in the console and seeing it appear, as it was indicated in the answers) - definitely not unclear enough to warrant being closed.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a failed question?

Comment: Several examples would be better. And remember that a question may seem clear, but when one of a number of "contexts" are missing, the question is unclear (or too broad).

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: You've come across it several times. Several examples, please. Here's one I came across recently. It is exactly clear what is wanted in broad general terms, but given there are at least four ways to do it (as asked originally) and the *reason* for wanting to slow down user response-time was not stated, I flagged it as unclear. Note, the question has been improved since originally asked. Seriously.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29665127/1) is the revision of the question that was closed. Perhaps the audit should show that revision instead of the (much improved) current one.

Comment: That would make much more sense - the original is completely unclear. I assumed that was what it was doing.

Comment: How far back are the other examples that you're referring to? I'm going through your reviews now, and I'm only seeing this one.

Comment: I'm not certain - it's been coming up for a while, but this is the first time I've gotten around to posting about it as I felt this was particularly bad one.

Comment: In my opinion people should choose the close reason more carefully. questions sometimes are closed for the wrong reasons. perhaps people should be more aware of the fact that they can select `off topic` and specify the close reason as free text.

Comment: Where is the free text option? If I try to flag as off-topic, I get 7 options and none of them allows me to enter free text. Is it a privilege that comes with more reputation?